# Does wielding an improvised weapon allow for attacks of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, improvised-weaponry

Would a fighter wielding a torch in his primary hand and holding a large shield in the other hand be allowed to perform an Attack of Opportunity with the torch from an opponent who provoked one in the area he threatens by trying to move past him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The typical not-[flat-footed](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#flat-footed) fighter *can* make an [attack of opportunity](http://dndsrd.net/initiativeAndAoO.html#attacks-of-opportunity) with the [torch](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#torch) in this situation

A typical Medium creature that's carrying in one hand a torch and employing in its other hand a readied [heavy shield](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#shield-heavy-wooden-or-steel) and that's not [flat-footed](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#flat-footed) typically threatens all of its adjacent squares with *both* the heavy shield *and* the torch and is capable of making one [attack of opportunity](http://dndsrd.net/initiativeAndAoO.html#attacks-of-opportunity) with the creature's choice of *either* the torch *or* the heavy shield.

Unless the DM rules otherwise, a creature wielding an improvised melee weapon threatens an area just like the creature would with a normal melee weapon. Further, the torch has actual rules supporting its use as an improvised weapon. A creature that's carrying a [torch](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#torch) can "treat it as a one-handed [improvised weapon](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#improvised-weapons) [i.e. typically suffering a -4 nonproficiency penalty on attack rolls with it]… that deals bludgeoning damage equal to that of a [gauntlet](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#gauntlet) of its size [i.e. 1d3 points of bludgeoning damage for Medium creature], plus [presumably if lit] 1 point of fire damage" (*Player's Handbook* 127 and links mine). (Note that while a torch *deals damage* as if it were a gauntlet, a torch—fortunately—shares none of a gauntlet's [considerable](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30514/8610) [quirks!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12808/8610))

A creature that's carrying a heavy shield can make a [shield bash attack](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#heavy-shield-bash-attacks). While shield bashes mentions using a shield as an off-hand weapon, a shield can also be used instead as a creature's main weapon *à la* Captain America and the *D&D Main FAQ* (52). (I'm certain a more authoritative source for shield bashing as a primary weapon exists elsewhere, but the *FAQ*'s answer is convenient, accessible, and—I believe [in this case](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610)—accurate.) However, making a shield bash—even as an attack of opportunity—causes the typical attacker until the attacker's next turn to lose the shield's shield bonus to AC.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the possibility to make an attack of opportunity with a torch as the rule (Compendium p.151) states that "Sometimes objects not **crafted** to be weapons see use in combat" which confirms it is an object and you shouldn't be considered "armed" (as the rule state is required for an attack of opportunity p.18 of Compendium).  To be armed is to have a weapon in your hands.  Having an object just allows you to attack with it but doesn't make the object a weapon. Of course the example would still allow for an attack of opportunity with the shield.  Unless I missed smethng

Comment: @jonDraco In that comment, I'm unclear on the importance of the weapon's origin when determining whether a creature with the weapon threatens with it. That is, whether an object is crafted to be weapon or not, it's being used *as* a weapon, and with weapons a wielder can make attacks, and [attacks of opportunity](http://dndsrd.net/initiativeAndAoO.html#attacks-of-opportunity) are attacks. (That is, combatants "threaten all squares into which [they] can make a melee attack[s]" (*PH* 137).

Comment: @jonDraco Note also that I hedged a little at the beginning of that second paragraph—a DM could totally rule otherwise. I agree that the improvised weapon rules are certainly not as clear as they could be!